# Style and link citations in Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, csl

I am using the IEEE citation style from http://www.zotero.org/styles/ieee with Pandoc in a project.

When I cite a reference, it shows up as `1` in the text, whereas I would like it to show up as `[1]`.

I have located this fragment in the `ieee.csl` file that I assume I need to edit:

```
212   <!-- Citation -->
213   <citation collapse="citation-number">
214     <sort>
215       <key variable="citation-number"/>
216     </sort>
217     <layout delimiter=", ">
218       <group prefix="[" suffix="]" delimiter=", ">
219         <text variable="citation-number"/>
220         <text macro="citation-locator"/>
221       </group>
222     </layout>
223   </citation>
```

I have two questions:

- How do I make it show the square brackets on single citations?
- How do I make it link to the citation at the end of the document?

Comment: For linking, see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1117 (not yet possible).

Comment: How are you citing references? The style should already include brackets (see the brackets on line 218 in your snippet).

Comment: @RintzeZelle: It's starting to work now (as of 5 days ago... ) -- see link you linked to     :)

Answer (score 2):

For linking back to the citation, this is starting to work now. See

- https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1117 , which says:

> *"I have just pushed a change to pandoc-citeproc that gives you clickable years (which link to the corresponding bibliography entry) in author-year citation formats. Note that this does not yet work with numerical citation styles."* (JGM)

This will likely arrive in the next major release of Pandoc, v1.14.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will give it a try as soon as the homebrew distribution gets updated.